# OpenOffice JAVA LANDSCAPE format

Tags: java, landscape, openoffice.org

To make a OdfTextDocument with landscape format I had to make one odt  empty file with landscape format  and use it . Is is possible to define the landscape via the API  ?

Comment: Are you developing extension for OpenOffice or using third-party library to create ODF files? You should look for page style manipulation via API, there landscape pages could be defined.

Comment: I used the same method as above, that is to create a document and format it as landscape, when I add further pages via API however the new pages have the default vertical format. So the lanscape mode seems to be a per-page setting!